# Graph on argand plane

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, graphing-functions

{$i+\bar z:1<|z|<4, z \in \mathbb{C}$}. If I want to shade this region in Argand plane, is it from z=i+4 to z=i-4?[image]

How can I justify this answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The region defined by $1< |z| < 4$ is the open annulus. Conjugating the annulus (i.e., $\bar{z}$ flips the annulus across the horizontal axis, which in this case has no effect. Then, adding $i$ translates the annulus.

Comment: so my answer is wrong? ok I will fix.